# Java Process Class: Why command "java -version" does not produce outputstream while command "ls -l" does?

Tags: java, java-11

Below program:

```
public class ProcessExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

        Process process1 = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/ls", "-l").directory(Path.of("/home/yapkm01").toFile()).start();
        System.out.println("ls command:");
        try (var in = new Scanner(process1.getInputStream())) {
            while (in.hasNextLine()) {
                System.out.println(in.nextLine());
            }
        }

        Process process2 = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/java", "-version").start();
        System.out.println("java command:");
        try (var in = new Scanner(process2.getInputStream())) {
            while (in.hasNextLine()) {
                System.out.println(in.nextLine());
            }
        }

    }

}
```

Output:

```
ls command:
total 424
drwxr-xr-x  2 yapkm01 yapkm01   4096 Dec 27  2021 Desktop
drwxr-xr-x  2 yapkm01 yapkm01   4096 Apr 30 01:09 Documents
drwxr-xr-x  2 yapkm01 yapkm01   4096 Jul  1 12:06 Downloads
-rw-r--r--  1 yapkm01 yapkm01   8980 Aug  3  2018 examples.desktop
java command:
```

Notice there is not output for process2 which is java -version. Of course when do i it manually i get below.

```
yapkm01-/home/yapkm01):-$ java -version
openjdk version "11.0.16" 2022-07-19
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 11.0.16+8-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 11.0.16+8-post-Ubuntu-0ubuntu122.04, mixed mode, sharing)
(yapkm01-/home/yapkm01):-$
```

Question: Why there is no output for java -version?

Comment: `java -version` writes to STDERR, you need to use `getErrorStream()`

Comment: Or use `java --version`, which for some reason prints to stdout

Comment: @tgdavies It is 'linux style' to print version info to stdout, and `--version` is the linuxy style version. Changing `-version` now would not be backwards compatible (although all the command line tools aren't part of any official spec as far as I know, so this is as usual Oracle/team OpenJDK cherrypicking a little bit).

Comment: @user207421 This topic is covered under multithreading in CoreJava vol 1 11Ed. If you think about it, yes. It should tag under multithreading because you're spinning off a process within your code.

Comment: Note you can use [`redirectErrorStream(true)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#redirectErrorStream(boolean)) so that the process's error stream will be redirected to its standard output. That means you only have to worry about reading the one stream, which additionally means you don't have to worry about spawning threads to read the two streams, but it also means the standard and error outputs can longer be distinguished easily.

Comment: @Slaw but even simpler is to use `inheritIO()` here, and remove the loops which do nothing but copy the output.

Comment: @Holger Depends on how you want to handle the output. Maybe you want to add the output to a GUI.

Comment: @rzwitserloot For the specification for the tools, look at the [JDK Tool Specifications](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/18/docs/specs/man/index.html)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
$ java --help | grep version
    -version      print product version to the error stream and exit
    --version     print product version to the output stream and exit
    -showversion  print product version to the error stream and continue
    --show-version
                  print product version to the output stream and continue
```

As you can see, `java -version` prints to stderr so obviously you won't see the output in stdout. You need to use `java --version` or capture stderr

Comment: But also, `/bin/java` from the question probably isn't the correct binary path anyway

Answer (score 1):

I think this question is really about learning about running subprocesses, based on the name 'ProcessExample'.

However, if what you really want is the version of Java your program is running (which is of course not necessarily the same version that an arbitrary "java" command line will use), then

```
String version = System.getProperty("java.version")
```